# Can you assign index values to .Currentpage VBA/Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a Macro that will, among other things, set the `.CurrentPage` to a specific value. My question is can you use an index value instead of the name of one of the values?

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("starttime").CurrentPage = "11/19/2018"
```

Here is an example line that I'm using. The problem is the dates will change every week to represent the new data. However there will always be five options, Monday to Friday. So instead of having to use the date, which I'll have to change every week, can I use an index value instead?

I.e. [0] for Monday and [4] for Friday etc. If this is possible then what is the correct syntax for this? I've looked all over the web and found nothing even remotely related to using index numbers instead of values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know that your field will only contain the relevant items and nothing else, then:

```
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("starttime")
    .CurrentPage = .PivotItems(3).Value
End With
```

However pivot tables may [retain](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.pivotcache.missingitemslimit) items deleted from the data source. If that is how it is set up for you, then you will either need to remove cached items before using this code, or calculate that page value instead of looking it up in the list of available values, which should be not difficult given that it is based on the current week.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this and get back to you. It's a fresh sheet every week thats exported from external software so I don't think the cache thing should be a problem

Comment: It gives me a Compile Error, Invaid or unqualified reference and it highlights .PivotItems

Comment: @S.Trott Did you lose the `With` line?

Comment: Apologies that was the case, I've added the With and End With and it now works correctly, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
Public arrDate(4) As Date

Sub CreateDateArray()

Dim i As Integer

For i = 0 To 4
    arrDate(i) = DateAdd("d", -Weekday(Date, vbMonday) + (i + 1), Date)
Next i

End Sub
```

or something like this

```
Function DateFromIndex(intDay As Integer) As Date

DateFromIndex = DateAdd("d", -Weekday(Date, vbMonday) + (intDay+1), Date)

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but I don't think I need to mess around with dates. To my understanding all its currently doing is searching for a text based value. (11/19/2018) as text. There are always five values and they're always in order by smallest to largest so I'm just wondering if there's a way to select the first index instead of querying it for the actual date.

http://prntscr.com/lnoa2f Here is an image to help explain, these are the options under the filter in the pivot table, do these correspond to indexes or do I have to use the exact value